# How do I define the iPhone SDK to use when building with Flash Develop?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, flash, flash-builder

Making an update to my iOS app which is built with Flash using Flash Builder 4.7.  I'm getting feedback from Apple that "Your app contains a launch image with a size modifier that is only supported for apps built with the iOS 6.0 SDK or later." -- So I downloaded the latest iPhone SDK (6.1).  How do I tell Flash Builder to target this SDK when building my app?
Thanks!

Update: here's my descriptor file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.4">

<id>com.bitty.dicesquared</id> <!-- Bundle Identifier. Required. -->
<filename>DiceSquared</filename> <!-- Used as the filename for the application. Required. -->
<name>dice²</name> <!-- The name that is displayed below the app icon. -->
<versionNumber>1.3</versionNumber> <!-- Required. -->

<!-- Settings for the application's initial window. Required. -->
<initialWindow>
    <!-- The main SWF or HTML file of the application. Required. -->
    <content>[This value will be overwritten by Flash Builder in the output app.xml]</content>

    <!-- The initial aspect ratio ("portrait" or "landscape"). Optional. -->
    <aspectRatio>portrait</aspectRatio>

    <!-- Whether the app will begin auto-orienting on launch. Optional. Default false -->
    <autoOrients>false</autoOrients>

    <!-- Whether the app launches in full screen. Optional. Mobile only. Default false -->
    <!-- (On iOS, this decides if the StatusBar is visible or not.) -->
    <fullScreen>true</fullScreen>

    <!-- Either auto, cpu, gpu, or direct. Default auto -->
    <renderMode>direct</renderMode>

    <!-- Whether direct mode allocates storage for depth and stencil buffers. Default false -->
    <!-- <depthAndStencil></depthAndStencil> -->

    <!-- Whether or not to pan when a soft keyboard is raised or lowered (either "pan" or "none").  Optional.  Defaults "pan." -->
    <!-- <softKeyboardBehavior></softKeyboardBehavior> -->
<visible>true</visible>
</initialWindow>

<!-- Languages supported by application. Only these languages can be specified. -->
<!-- <supportedLanguages>en de cs es fr it ja ko nl pl pt ru sv tr zh</supportedLanguages> -->

<!-- The icon the system uses for the application. Optional. -->
<!-- Place the icons in a 'source path' (e.g. in the 'src' directory). -->
<!-- iPhone: 57x57, iPhone HD: 114x114, iPad: 72x72, iPad HD: 144x144 -->
<icon>
    <image57x57>icon57.png</image57x57>
    <image72x72>icon72.png</image72x72>
    <image114x114>icon114.png</image114x114>
    <image144x144>icon144.png</image144x144>
</icon>

<!-- iOS specific capabilities -->
<iPhone>
    <!-- A list of plist key/value pairs to be added to the application Info.plist -->
    <!-- UIDeviceFamily: 1 - iPhone/iPod Touch; 2 - iPad; both: universal app -->

    <InfoAdditions><![CDATA[            
        <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
        <array>
            <string>1</string>
            <string>2</string>
        </array>
    ]]></InfoAdditions>

    <!-- Display Resolution for the app ("standard" or "high"). Optional. Default "standard" -->
    <requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>
</iPhone>
```

Comment: You should only need to select an iOS SDK if using Adobe Native Extension that requires it.

I suspect problem is something to do with the settings in your application descriptor file. can you post its contents?

Comment: Updated to include the app descriptor file.  Nothing's changed since I published the previous version... confused!

Comment: Actually, i now think its related to the hi-res splash page - do you have a ..@2x.png file? I successfully submitted to apple a couple days ago without ..@2x.png file and requestedDisplayResolution = standard. Not sure of solution if you need retina support (ie: res = high)

Comment: Yeah I do need high res.  This is really odd because none of this stuff has changed since my last release/update of the same game!  I did change my flash builder 4.7 from the free trial to the full purchased version, but that's all I can think of that's different!

Comment: I see the answer on this page: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WSe4e4b720da9dedb5-2e7310a1136ab7c1811-8000.html#WSe4e4b720da9dedb5-2e7310a1136ab7c1811-7ffc - iOS 5 is bundled with AIR 3.4 - but apparently I can "configure an iOS SDK by using the AIR Developer Tool (ADT). Flash Builder lets you select the location of the supported external iOS SDK using the Package Settings dialog. After you select the location of the iOS SDK, the selected location is passed through the -platformsdk ADT command." ... can't figure out how to do this though! :(

Comment: Apple are always tweaking their submission process - it can work fine one day and fail the next :(

Comment: Try adding "-platformsdk PATH_TO_YOUR_SDK" to compiler settings in FB

Comment: tried that, but it said it wasn't a valid compiler setting?!  doing a software update now - I see there's AIR 3.5 now - might solve things!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found here: http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/flash-builder-47-update-tips
The update to AIR 3.5 fixed the problem.